# JQuery/HTML: How to use variable within onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm really stuck on this project that I'm doing. Below is my code. I am using the Google Maps API by the way.

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = lat1, lon1
arr[1] = lat2, lon2
arr[2] = lat3, lon3
for (each i in arr){
    var newCenter = "<button onClick='map.setCenter(arr[i])'>Center Map</button>";
    $("#myTable").append(newCenter);
}
```

Now I know that

```
'map.setCenter(arr[i])'
```

is incorrect because it's basically hard coding "arr[i]" into the DOM. What I want to do is use arr[i] as a variable so that the DOM has:

```
<button onClick='map.setCenter(arr[0])'>Center Map</button>
<button onClick='map.setCenter(arr[1])'>Center Map</button>
<button onClick='map.setCenter(arr[2])'>Center Map</button>
```

I have tried

```
"<button onClick='map.setCenter(" + arr[i] + ")'>Center Map</button>"
```

but that doesn't work. I have been stuck on this for a pretty long time. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with: `arr[0] = lat1, lon1`.  That is not putting two values into the array item.  Do you mean this: `arr[0] = {lat1, lon1}`

Comment: I apologize for being so sloppy. The code was shorten dramatically. The arr[i] is just an arbitrary latitude, longitude coordinates pulled from something else using the Google Maps API. The main concern is that I can't get arr[i] to act as a variable in onClick.

Comment: If you want help, then use the Edit button to please correct your code.  We can't tell where the problems are if you have all sort of errors in the code you present.  `i` is probably not defined in your onclick handler.

Comment: jfriend00, I feel so retarded posting my code like that. I apologize. I'll ask my professor about this tomorrow and if he can't help, I'll link my whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- to loop an array you use  `for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ;i++)` and **not** the `in` operator.

2- You need to create your links on a separate function to obtain closure, ([**explanation here**](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm))

3- you array should hold `google.maps.LatLng()` objects.

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat1, lon1);
arr[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat2, lon2);
arr[2] = new google.maps.LatLng(lat3, lon3);


for (var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ;i++) {
    var button = createbutton(arr[i],i);
 }

function createbutton(latlon,index) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var container = document.getElementById('containerDiv');
    button.onclick = function(){map.setCenter(latlon)};
    button.value = 'Center Map at ' + index;
    container.appendChild(button);
}
```

...and in your HTML:

```
<div id ="containerDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You definitely know what I'm trying to do! Ok, what I have so far are multiple markers on the map. My task is to create a button on a web page for each of those markers. The button is to set the center on the map corresponding to that marker. "arr[i]" are basically the location of the markers. Your solution was very close but for some reason I'm getting a "[object HTMLButtonElement]" message where the actual button is supposed to be.

Comment: That message is probably related to the way jQuery appends the button to the table. Does your table have rows and cells?

Comment: Yes I am using rows and columns. This is what my append function looks like so far:

$("#myTable").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td>" + "<td>" + button + "</td></tr>");

Comment: That doesn't look like a function that will do anything. I've edited the answer to simply append the buttons into a <div>. Next time, please post your complete code. :-)

Comment: Believe I have been contemplating on posting the whole code for you guys because that would make it a lot easier. The thing is this has been a 2 week school project and I didn't want to get in trouble from other students blatantly stealing my code. If things don't work out tomorrow from the professor I will link you my whole code.

Comment: If someone steals your code they, (the thieves), are the ones who'd get into trouble. You'd only be the victim. ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19292/discussion-between-cyn-and-marcelo)

Comment: Just wanted to say with your help, I got it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (each i in arr){
```

supposed to be

```
for (var i in arr){
```

Also `arr[0] = lat1, lon1`  does not mean anything in the first place

**FULL Code**

```
for (var i in arr){
    var newCenter = "<button onClick='map.setCenter("+ arr[i] + ")'>Center Map</button>";
    $("#myTable").append(newCenter);
}
```

Comment: Sorry that was actually a typo when I was trying to type a shorter version of my code. I do have "var i in arr"